# valid and invalid syntax for representing the size of array during initialisation

Tags: c, arrays

I'm currently studying c array and is confused about what can and can't be used to represent the size of the array during initialisation.

Am I right to assume

```
#define SIZE 5
```

and

```
const int SIZE = 5;
```

are fundamentally different to one another?

They have their difference and one particular example that confuses me is

```
#define SIZE 5
int arr[SIZE] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
```

is valid syntax, but

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int arr[SIZE] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
```

is not valid syntax. Though interestingly,

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int arr[SIZE];
```

is valid syntax.

What's the logic behind whether a particular syntax is valid or invalid?

Comment: They are all valid syntax. Some of them are constraint violations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Am I right to assume
>
> #define SIZE 5
>   and
>   const int SIZE = 5;
>
> are fundamentally different to one another?

Yes, you are right.

`#define` is simply a [textual replacement](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-macros.html). Basically, the C preprocessor is going a "find and replace" for you during the compilation process (processing stage). Whereas, `const` qualified  object means "the thing stored at this location can't changed" - roughly equivalent to saying it's "read-only".

---

> #define SIZE 5
>      int arr[SIZE] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
>
> is valid syntax.

This is exactly equivalent to writing:

```
int arr[5] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
```

yourself. The compiler simply does the replacement job for you when you use `define`.

---

> const int SIZE = 5;
>
> int arr[SIZE] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
>
> is not valid syntax.

It's invalid but the reason could be more than one. If `arr` has static storage duration (i.e., the object `arr` is alive throughout the program execution) then it's invalid. Because C requires that the size of an array object with static storage duration to be a [*constant expression*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4):

> If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

So, the following program is not valid:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int arr[SIZE] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
int main(void)
{
}
```

because `SIZE` doesn't qualify as a "constant expression" in C. Note that this is totally valid in C++ where `SIZE` qualifies as a constant expression (the two languages differ here).

Another reason is C standard doesn't allow *initializing* variable-length arrays. If you have the definition inside a function such as:

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type.

So if you don't have the initializer then it becomes valid:

```
int main(void)
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int arr[SIZE];  /* This is OK */
}
```

Similarly, you can do without the `const` as well:

```
int main(void)
{
    int SIZE = 5;
    int arr[SIZE]; /* Thi is OK too. */
}
```

In both of the above snippets, `arr` is simply a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

> Though interestingly,
>
> const int SIZE = 5;
>   int arr[SIZE];
>
> is valid syntax.

It's valid only if it's inside a function (as above) - it's a VLA. But if you make it have *static storage duration* such as:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int arr[SIZE]; /* arr has static storage duration just as
                 all objects defined at file scope */

int main(void)
{
}
```

it's invalid because as noted above, `SIZE` is not a ["constant expression"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p2) in C.

Similarly,

```
int main(void)
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    static int arr[SIZE]; /* arr has static storage duration */
}
```

is invalid for the same reason, despite `arr` being inside a function, because `arr` has *static storage duration*.

---

However, if you have:

```
enum {SIZE = 5};
int arr[SIZE] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
 int arr2[SIZE]; /* Valid without initializer too. */

int main()
{
}
```

it's valid. Why? Because [enum constants qualify as "constant expressions"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p3) in C.

Comment: «Note that this is totally valid in C++ where SIZE qualifies as a constant expression (the two languages differ here» This has always been bothering me – why in the world would these two languages differ in such a simple thing?

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov because they are two different languages, and there is no reason to bog down the evolution of C++ with historical crud

Comment: @M.M Fixed the quote (and link). Thanks. Re. Grigory's question: would it be valid a C compiler treats `SIZE` (as in `const int SIZE=5;`) as "constant expression"? To my reading, the definition of "constant expression" (n1570, 6.6p2) allows such an interpretation.

Comment: @M.M Can one think *the other way around* and bring C closer to all the magnificent glory of C++'s perfection? That is, to allow `const int` expressions be allowed for specifying array sizes in same situations it is now allowed in C++?

Answer (score 8):

The standard explains it [6.7.9p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p3)

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type.

In the second case it's a VLA but in the first case it is not. After preprocessing it is same as `int arr[5] = {..}`.

In the VLA case, the compiler doesn't know the size of a VLA when it's defined, so it can't check validity of an initializer. That's why this initialization is not allowed.

By the way, using `const` doesn't mean that it is a compile time constant - it just means it can't be changed.

Also from [6.7.6.2p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4) there is a clear distinction about when it is VLA and when it is not:-

> ...If the size is an **integer constant expression** and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

Answer (score 6):

`#define SIZE 5` define `SIZE` an *integer constant expression*. While `const int SIZE = 5;` defines `SIZE` as a *variable expression* that's value shall not be modified. `const` qualifier doesn't make it an integer constant expression (in c++ it does so).

Standard says

n1570-§6.7.6.2 (p4):

> [...] If the size is an *integer constant expression* and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type. [...]

When you do

```
#define SIZE 5
int arr[SIZE] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
```

it declare `arr` as an array which is not a variable length array (VLA). While

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int arr[SIZE];
```

declares `arr` as a variable length array because `SIZE` is not a *integer constant expression*, but a variable expression. But same declaration fails with initializer list and that's because there is a restriction on VLA's is they can't be initialized using list intializers.

§6.7.9 (p2 and p3):

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.
>
> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type **that is not a variable length array type**.